# Create Copy and Paste function with Python

Tags: python, copy-paste

I am looking for a solution to add a function to a program using Python. I want to copy and paste selected data (selected with the mouse).

Example:

1. Copy "Hello" using CTRL-C from the sentence "Hello everybody" when I select Hello.
2. Copy a part of array selected using CTRL-C

My main problem is how to use the selected data.  But now I just can copy string defined in the code (here "tt"):

```
clipboard.OpenClipboard()
clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
clipboard.SetClipboardText('tt')
clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

I tried several codes found on the internet and in this website but none of them fixed my problem.

Comment: You should cut down your post to keep only the essentials. This will increase your chance of getting help. For guidance, see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you Jean-François Corbett, I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `clipboard.SetClipboardText()`. When a program supports the clipboard, then <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> will copy the currently selected text into the clipboard. There is nothing you need to do to make this happen.

If your question is "How can I trigger <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> from outside of a program to copy the currently selected text into the clipboard", then the answer is: Usually, you can't. For security reasons, most programs don't respond to artificial key events which other programs send them.

The second error is something else entirely. Your class `CopyEvent` doesn't have a property `list`, so Python can't invoke methods in it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The programs doesn't support Ctr+C. I have to code the function to copy the selected data.

Comment: Which UI elements do you use to display "Hello everybody"?

Comment: Thank you for your response, finally I find a solution so I will not keep you busy more long.

Answer (score 0):

The final code if someone is interested:

```
from eventbase import EventBase

import win32clipboard as clipboard
import os

import wx

class CopyEvent(EventBase):
    TYPE = wx.NewEventType()
    ID = wx.NewId()
    BINDER = wx.PyEventBinder(TYPE, 1)    
    SHORTCUT_MODIFIER = wx.ACCEL_CTRL
    SHORTCUT_KEY = ord('C')

    def __init__(self, variable=None):
        EventBase.__init__(self)
        self._variable = variable

    def execute(self, viewmodel, parent):
        clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
        text = self._convert_variable_to_text(self._variable)
        clipboard.SetClipboardText(text)
        clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        self.logger.info("Copying variable to clipboard")

    def _convert_variable_to_text(self, variable)            :
        lines = []
        lines.append("\t".join(variable.column_names))
        for row_nbr in variable.row_numbers:
            lines.append("\t".join([repr(i) for i in variable.get_row_as_tuple(row_nbr)]))
        return os.linesep.join(lines)
```

Comment: Some comments: 1. I don't see why this needs to be an event. Secondly, you should give an example for `variable`.

Comment: Ok thank you for all you help. I did an event because all the program is coded with events, so I want to follow how they build it.
Here variable is a table shown in a window of the program.